# What would be the down sides of running a VPS on GMT time instead of American time?

Tags: vps, time, timezone

I have a VPS which is hosted in America somewhere. It's alright and does a job.

However, while configuring the web mail system on the VPS, I noticed that the time displayed was for America and not for the UK (where I'm based and where most of the customers will be from too).

I want to change the time on the server to be on GMT time and not on the current time zone it's already on. I'm wondering though that would this cause the VPS problems and potentially break it?

Comment: Except for scheduled jobs expressed in local time, the machine itself is operating in UTC/GMT. If anything, you get rid of any stupidity involving Daylight Savings Time, since there's no shift with UTC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It shouldn't cause any problems, although you might want to reboot the machine after you make the change, just to make sure everything's picked up the right timezone (one process that's held onto the old timezone, doing some logging, can really confuse you).

Answer (score 1):

The timezone setting of your OS is unrelated to any functionality, other than how times and dates are displayed and interpreted.

If you provide UK services I would set the server to UTC/GMT.